"TypeError: command.resolveMiddleware is not a function" with DynamoDBDocumentClient and UpdateCommand
I'm running the following code in a lambda, and I'm receiving the following error
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "command.resolveMiddleware is not a function",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: command.resolveMiddleware is not a function",
        "    at _DynamoDBDocumentClient.send (/var/task/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:111:29)",
        "    at Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.js:28:25)",
        "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"
    ]
}


when sending the command via the docClient. Taking away some of the console logging and business logic, the line it's referring to would be the line that is sending the update command.
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient, UpdateCommand } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

export const handler = async (event) => {
    const { userId, id, processedPurchases } = event;

    const key = {
        userId: userId,
        id: id
    };

    try {
        const updateCommand = buildUpdateCommand(key, processedPurchases);
        console.log(updateCommand);

        await docClient.send(updateCommand);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(`There was an error processing transaction ${id} from ${userId}`, e);
        throw e;
    }

};

function buildUpdateCommand(key, processedPurchases) {

    const pPurchases = [some code]

    const orderEvent = {some code}

    const updateCommand = new UpdateCommand({
        TableName: process.env.TABLENAME,
        Key: key,
        UpdateExpression: 'SET orderHistory = list_append(orderHistory, :orderEvent), SET processedPurchases = :processedPurchases',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':processedPurchases': pPurchases,
            ':orderEvent': orderEvent
        }
    });

    return updateCommand;
}

I'm printing out the updateCommand, and it's matching the UpdateCommand type, so I don't know what's happening here.

Can you share the full stacktace?

@Mureinik Updated the OP with the full stacktrace!

If you're not in 'us-east-1', you will have to configure the client to its region.
For example: new DynamoDBClient({region:"ap-south-1"});

My import statements:

import ddb from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";
import * as dynamodb from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
const docClient = new dynamodb.DynamoDBClient();
const ddbDocClient = ddb.DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(docClient, {
marshallOptions: {
removeUndefinedValues: true,
},
});


const update_dynamo = async (params) => {
try {
let command = new ddb.UpdateCommand(params);
await ddbDocClient.send(command);
return "Success";
}
catch (err) {
console.log(params, err);
throw new Error(err);
 }
};
// I call the functions wherever i need using await. This feels so easy.
//Example: await update_dynamo(updateProfileParams);
//Similarly, for all ops.

